# React Native run-android not working

Tags: node.js, react-native

React Native run-android shows starting js server... but no server is started like it was starting before (nodejs winodow opens) and in the end it show following error:

```
Running C:\users\deepa\appdata\local\android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 
192.168.105.101:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Starting the app on 192.168.105.101:5555 
(C:\users\deepa\appdata\local\android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 
192.168.105.101:5555 shell am start -n 
com.aptencemobileapp/com.aptencemobileapp.MainActivity)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.aptencemobileapp/.MainActivity }
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Please someone help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved it!
I reinstalled react-native-cli , nodejs added all paths to system  and run following command.

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but sometimes I also got the same error. You just need to clean android  build using following command.

- goto your projrct android folder using  `cd android`
- hit the `gradlew clean`
- again run the same command you are running.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: If it's not working then delete node_modules folder and run again npm install command

Comment: already tried that too . Actually when i hit react-native run-android it shows starting JS server... but no server is started automatically. But when i manually hit npm start, server starts but then i'm unable to access debugging mode

Comment: Run your server on different port like react-native start --port 8090 and then run react-native run-android --port 8090